# Archiving my flutter Project in Xcode fails because of .h file not found

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, flutter, firebase-mlkit

I'm trying to upload my flutter app to the app store. Everything works except archiving the project in XCode.
Everytime I try to archive the project, I get the error:

> 'firebase_ml_vision/FirebaseMlVisionPlugin.h' file not found.

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v1.9.1+hotfix.2, on Mac OS X 10.14.6 18G95, locale de-DE)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.0)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.38.0)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.31.1)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: have you executed the command `flutter build ios`?

Comment: Yes! Also  flutter build ios --release ...

Comment: anything to do with this? https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/23259#issuecomment-473461289

Comment: Nope. I increased the build target to 9.0 and the issue still exists...